# Save a bitmap in internal cache folder

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap, storage

I need to do several SIMPLE things... but I can't get it right

- Save bitmap to internal cache for later use, for now I save the name (ex : name_2347458.jpg)

I tried this kind of approach :

```
public static void saveFile(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String picName) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(picName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "io exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It saves the file but I don't know where ?

With getExternalCacheDir() I can see the file on the device but not with openFileOutput.

I can load the bitmap with :

```
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Context context, String picName) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    try {
        fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(picName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "io exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

But again just using the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It saves the file but I don't know where ?

It saves it in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

> I can load the bitmap with

Then your code would seem to be working just fine.

Comment: It should be at something like  Android/data/packageName/cache ? but i don't see any directory with my application package name

Comment: @An-droid: This is all covered in [the blog post that I linked to in my answer](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You cannot browse internal storage using ordinary tools.